# Either my javascript is not working, or the function isn't being called

Tags: javascript, html

My code is supposed to change the text of a paragraph.
The code- (both .js and .html files)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Java's Crypt</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p Id="bello">i will change</p>
   <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">click to change</button>
   <script src="crypt.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(javascript file)

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("bello").innerhtml = "toldya";
}
```

Comment: You want to set innerText `document.getElementById("bello").innerText = "toldya";`.

Comment: Please check documentation about [how to write id attribute in html](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and how to write  [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)  --- id -from small letter, innerHTML with HTML capitalize

Comment: in 2 lines you create 2 mistakes:  `<p id="bello">i will change</p>` and `document.getElementById("bello").innerHTML = "toldya";`

Answer (score 1):

First there is `id` not `Id` in HTML

```
<p id="bello">i will change</p>
```

and in JS, You can use `textContent` or `innerText` to change text

```
document.getElementById("bello").textContent = "toldya";
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("bello").textContent = "toldya";
}
```

```html
<p id="bello">i will change</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">click to change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Jax-p's comment, `document.getElementById("bello").innerText = "toldya";` should work.

Also, it is best practice to use lower case for your html attributes e.g. `Id` should just be `id`

Comment: Thanks, both jax-p and you. It was a simple error lol, I'm new to javascript, just finished learning HTML :)